# Options for insulating glass sliding patio door in master bedroom other than replacing it?

Tags: insulation, doors, windows, patio

Our master bedroom is a lot colder than any other room in the house. From what I can see, the patio door is leaking in a lot of cold. We don't want to replace the entire patio door right now. Looking for something quick/inexpensive to last us through the winter.

I have uploaded some pictures of the door and what the temperature looks like around the room and near the door: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0rVB.jpg.

The edges of the windows in other rooms have similar numbers but they just have one window so its less of an issue. Maybe whatever solution I can find for the patio I can use for the other rooms too.

Comment: I don't see anything concerning there. It's perfectly reasonable to expect the air falling off that huge glass pane to be 10 degrees. Do you detect air leakage?

Comment: I don’t know. I’m not an expert. I just felt it colder there so I thought maybe air is leaking in. What options do I have for insulating?

Comment: I meant "... 10 degrees _cooler_", in case that wasn't apparent. You need to determine whether you have air leakage. If not, you could apply window film to add a layer of air, or you could put on some slippers. :)

Answer (score 1):

The sliding door that is installed may be a cheaper door and does not have a "thermal break" in it's construction. If you are the purchaser of one of these doors you should insure that the door has this thermal break. That said, one way to help correct this cold problem would be to make sure that the perimeter of the frame is sealed  (caulked) to lessen air infiltration. It can be carefully caulked on both the outside and the inside. Another "fix" would be to install a storm door for that sliding door. I know that these do work because I installed one in my last house where I had the same problem as yours. To find a storm door you could search for "patio storm doors. I searched and came up with Larson and Columbia. You could also shop for these at Lowes or Home Depot and they can have it installed for you if you want. Hpoe this helps.